# WinDBG - ASP.NET and VB.NET - .loadby sos clr

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windbg

I am trying to use WinDBG to create a breakpoint in a source file.  I have followed the advice here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22245/Quick-start-to-using-WinDbg, but when I press F5 I get an error which says:

```
Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 00db0861, Win32 error 0n998
    "Invalid access to memory location."
```

I have researched this error and discovered that it could be because I have not loaded the CLR i.e. .loadby sos clr.  However, when I run this statement I get an error, which says: Unable to find module 'clr'.  I am able to load the CLR if I follow the advice in this blog: http://humblecoder.co.uk/uncategorized/spotting-a-memory-leak-with-windbg-in-net, but this is for an ASP.NET application.

Therefore I am able to load SOS.DLL if I am debugging an ASP.NET application, which runs in a 64 bit process, but I am unable to load the CLR when running a VB.NET client app that runs in a 32 bit process.  Therefore I have two questions:

1) Is loading the SOS.DLL likely to resolve the original problem (unable to add breakpoint)
2) Why am I able to execute the .loadby sos clr statement when debugging an ASP.NET app, but not a VB.NET app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use !sosex.mbp and !sosex.mbm to set breakpoints, even before the CLR is loaded.

```
.load sosex

!mbp mysource.cs 23  <--sets a BP at mysource.cs, line 23.
```

Comment: .load sosex causes an error: The call to LoadLibrary(sosex) failed, Win32 error 0n2
    "The system cannot find the file specified."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.

Comment: When did you download that?  If you're running on XP, I posted a fix for that a couple of weeks ago.  If you just downloaded it from my website and you're still experiencing the problem, could you tell me the date/time of the binary?

Comment: Oh wait.  I'm sorry.  You have to download sosex (for free) from stevestechspot.com.  Then put it in your "winext" directory under your debugger install path.

Comment: Thanks.  I have added the following paths, but still I get the error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext;C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\winext

Comment: I have a Windows 7 64 bit PC.

Comment: You downloaded the zip file and extracted sosex.dll and placed it in the winext directory?  Are you debugging a 32-bit process or a 64-bit process?  For .NET debugging, you must match the "bitness" of the process and debugger.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13892/discussion-between-steve-johnson-and-w0051977)

Answer (score 0):

The "Unable to find module 'clr'" error is because [clr.dll isn't loaded yet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rihamselim/archive/2012/03/14/breaking-on-module-load.aspx). Add this breakpoint:

```
sxe ld clr
```

When it breaks, clr.dll will be loaded. Then you can do:

```
.loadby sos clr
```